# Aligning a Path within a Container, StackPane, VBox etc

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

If I try to align a Path in a StackPane, somehow it is aligned based on its internal structure rather than using the layout bounds. Is there anyway of changing this? I've tried all sorts of combinations of with/without Group wrapper, VBox, HBox, autosizeChildren property etc.

For example, I want the line to be inset by (50, 50), but it gets shown at (0, 0)

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo();
    moveTo.setX(50);
    moveTo.setY(50);
    LineTo lineTo = new LineTo();
    lineTo.setX(100);
    lineTo.setY(100);
    Path path = new Path(moveTo, lineTo);
    StackPane stack = new StackPane(new Group(path));
    stack.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(stack, 100, 100));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

[image: aligned based on structure]

Without using a StackPane it appears as I expect. the line starts at (50, 50)

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo();
    moveTo.setX(50);
    moveTo.setY(50);
    LineTo lineTo = new LineTo();
    lineTo.setX(100);
    lineTo.setY(100);
    Path path = new Path(moveTo, lineTo);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(path), 100, 100));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

[image: aligned based on layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`StackPane` Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html):

> The stackpane will attempt to resize each child to fill its content
>   area. If the child could not be sized to fill the stackpane (either
>   because it was not resizable or its max size prevented it) then it
>   will be aligned within the area using the alignment property, which
>   defaults to Pos.CENTER.

Since the `Path` is not resizable, is doesn't get resized, and just gets positioned according to the alignment you set. Wrapping in a `Group` doesn't help because the `Group` takes on the bounds of its children.

Either use a regular `Pane` instead of the `StackPane` (probably the most convenient solution):

```
Pane stack = new Pane(path);
```

or wrap the path in a `Pane` (which gets resized, etc):

```
StackPane stack = new StackPane(new Pane(path));
```

Comment: Excellent, many thanks, I'd tried wrapping with various things VBox etc, but missed Pane. I need to use StackPane as I'm using it to overlay graphics onto an existing display.

Comment: Note that `Pane` will also allow you to overlay nodes on top of each other, in the order in which they're added, so it may work. Wrapping works too, just adds a level of complexity you may not actually need.